# Hive not starting on CentOS

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using CDH 5.3. I have followed all the steps giving at https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example. However, I am stuck when I try to run Hive.

```
[cloudera@quickstart conf]$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
```

This is the output and nothing happens. It is stuck there.

This is my hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore</value>
<description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore</value>
<description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>mypassword</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
<description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share your hive site-xml ? Also are you using any RDMS for Metastore connection ?

Comment: I am using Mysql for metastore.